# self adhoc domain name for url in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have an url with domain name including static `http://www.domain1.com/myapp` in java code.

```
String url="http://www.domain1.com/myapp";
```

how do i configure domain name dynamically for the url that is the prefix of myapp if domain name changes to some other name eg : domain1 to domain2

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you.

```
static String url="http://www.%s.com/myapp";

private static String getDomainSpecificUrl(String domain){
    return String.format(url, domain);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {   
    URL netUrl = new URL(getDomainSpecificUrl("domain1"));
    String domainUrl = netUrl.getHost();
    int urlLength = netUrl.getHost().length();
    System.out.println(domainUrl.startsWith("www.") ? domainUrl.substring(4, urlLength - 4) : domainUrl.substring(0, urlLength - 4));
}
```

In case if you have no control over the static String then the other solution would be to write a regex to just get the domain name.